# get specific value from list object - python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a data like

```
sql = "select value, type from table"
cur.execute(sql)
row_headers = [x[0] for x in cur.description] #this will extract row headers
rv = cur.fetchall()
json_result = []
for result in rv:
    json_result.append(dict(zip(row_headers, result)))
finalresult = json.dumps(json_result)
#[{'value':30,'type':'SS'},{'value':40,'type':'KK'},{'value':80,'type':'SK'}]
attrList = list(map(lambda x: x['value'], finalresult))
return attrList
```

I want OP :

```
[30,40,80]
```

But I am getting ERROR :

```
attrList = list(map(lambda x: x['value'], finalresult))
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Where am I doing mistake?

Comment: Your code works fine for me!

Comment: No error is seen and the correct output is produced

Comment: https://ideone.com/hj7QUM

Comment: @bro-grammer check updated question

Comment: @MdJohirulIslam check the question now

Comment: `json.dumps` outputs string, where as you need a `list` of `dicts` to perform filteration. Comment out the `json.dumps` and try it again.

Comment: @bro-grammer ok but now TypeError: 'list' object is not callable